# Post date format error : Invalid date

Tags: jekyll

I understand that when you post stuff into your Jekyll blog you have to follow the format like so: 2014-12-3-New-Post.md. However, doing this is resulting in a build error every time. Is there a convention in

```
layout: post
title: "Title"
date: 2014-04-30
```

that needs to be followed too? Or in anywhere else in the site's files? I am getting build errors even when updating the main index.html file, and the updates are not showing in my website.

Answer (score 1):

The correct file name pattern for posts is : `YYYY-MM-DD-any-thing.md/html`

At build time, when you read :

> Invalid date 2016-4-35': Document '_posts/2016-4-35-prospectsofneurocomputing.md' does not have a valid date in the filename.

That means that your filename represents an invalid date because in **2016-4-35**:

- the month representation is not on two digit : **4** instead of **04**
- and the day representation is out of boundaries : **no** month has **35** days